# Postgres sql time zone

Tags: postgresql

I try return values for specific time zone and I faced with some strange behavior in response:

```
SELECT created_at AT TIME ZONE 'US/Pacific' - created_at,
       NOW() AT TIME ZONE 'US/Pacific' - NOW(),
       NOW() now  FROM "my_table" 
ORDER by id DESC LIMIT 1
```

return

```
10:00:00 | -10:00:00 | 2017-08-02 17:36:30.660477+03
```

why does same function return opposite values (-10/+10) for the column from the table and for dynamic time?

Thanks!

Comment: What type is column `created_at`?

Comment: `created_at` type is timestamp without timezone

Comment: Don't put "Solved" into the title. If Usagi's answer solved your problem, **accept** the answer. Otherwise this question remains "open"

Answer (score 3):

Type `timestamp without timezone` is interpreted as "local time zone".
Thus your `created_at AT TIME ZONE 'US/Pacific'` value is taken as a timestamp of the given timezone.

While `NOW()` returns `timestamp with timezone`, thus your `NOW() AT TIME ZONE 'US/Pacific'` value has to be converted to a different timezone.

See docs:

- [8.5.3 Time Zones](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-TIMEZONES)
- [9.9.3 AT TIME ZONE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-ZONECONVERT)

### EDIT

Try this:

```
SELECT created_at AT TIME ZONE 'US/Pacific' AS crated_at_us_pacific, created_at,
       NOW() AT TIME ZONE 'US/Pacific' AS now_us_pacific, NOW() AS now
   FROM "my_table"
   ORDER by id DESC
   LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Please. change your answer from `SELECT created_at AT TIME ZONE 'US/Pacific' AS ....` to `SELECT created_at AT TIME ZONE  'localtime' AT TIME ZONE 'US/Pacific' AS ....`. After that, I mark it as useful

Comment: The purpose of the `SELECT` statement was to show the reason why the values differed, not to give an advice how to resolve, as your question was "why"...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Usagi Miyamoto for some clarification it sent me to right track.

If field timestamp without timezone AT TIME ZONE define specific timezone. So first declare localtime and then turn it to specific timezone: So fixed SQL is:

```
SELECT created_at AT TIME ZONE 'localtime' AT TIME ZONE 'US/Pacific' - created_at,
       NOW() AT TIME ZONE 'US/Pacific' - NOW(),
       NOW() now  FROM "my_table" 
ORDER by id DESC LIMIT 1
```

**EDIT**

More dynamically

```
SELECT created_at::timestamptz AT TIME ZONE 'US/Pacific' - created_at,
       NOW() AT TIME ZONE 'US/Pacific' - NOW(),
       NOW() now  FROM "my_table" 
ORDER by id DESC LIMIT 1
```

first `timestamptz` converts time to local timezone and after that to timezone  which you need `AT TIME ZONE 'US/Pacific'`